# Why this C program execution stops working while inputting through scanf()?

Tags: c, linked-list, scanf

This is a simple C program to creat and display a singly linked-list.The creat() function creats a new node after the previous node taking the node-data as parameter.The display() function prints the linked-list. This program fragment is not working properly:

```
    for(b=1;b<=5;b++) {
    scanf("%d ",&a);
    creat(a);
    }
```

The execution stops working if two or three values are inserted through scanf().
   What's wrong with that?
   If you skip scanf() and put statements like below , it works:

```
    for(b=1;b<=5;b++) {
    creat(7);
    }
```

Main Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node
{
int data;
struct node *next;
} *head=NULL;

typedef struct node Node;

void creat(int d);
void display();

int main()
{
int a,b;
 printf("Input data to build a linked-list:\n");
  for(b=1;b<=5;b++) {
    scanf("%d ",&a);    /*Error statement maybe*/
    creat(a);

}
printf("The list is:-\n");

display();
return 0;

}
void creat(int d)
{

Node *new,*curr;

new=(Node *) malloc(sizeof(Node));
new->data=d;
new->next=NULL;

if(head==NULL)
{
    head=new;
    curr=new;
}
else
{
    curr->next=new;
    curr=new;
}

 }
void display()
{
Node *p;
p=head;
while(p)
{
    printf("%d--->",head->data);
    p=p->next;
}
printf("NULL\n");
}
```

Comment: `curr->next=new;` : `curr` is local variable. `scanf("%d ",&a);` --> `scanf("%d",&a);`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because linked-list with one of the usual bugs, (change to local var no propagated to caller), and no debugging.

Comment: Could you tell me how can I fix the bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually problem is created by function `creat()`-

`else` part in this function is creating problem. It should be like this -

```
else
{
    curr=head;
    while(curr->next!=NULL)
      {
          curr=curr->next;
      }
    curr->next=new;
}
```

Traversing to last node and adding the new node.

And as well as `scanf`.

```
  scanf("%d ",&a);    /*Error statement maybe*/
           ^Remove the space.
```

Also in function `void display()`

```
while(p)
{  
    printf("%d--->",head->data);
    p=p->next;
 }
```

You are printing `head->data` but it is not incrementated to its next rather `p` is set to `p->next` .Thus , this function will not print whole link list .

`printf` should be this -

```
    printf("%d--->",p->data);
```

Answer (score 0):

try without the space after the %d - scanf can be rather fragile....

```
scanf("%d",&a);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. `} *head=NULL;` change to `} *head=NULL, *curr;`
2. `scanf("%d ",&a);` change to `scanf("%d",&a);`
3. `Node *new,*curr;` change to `Node *new;`
4. `printf("%d--->", head->data);` change to `printf("%d--->", p->data);`